# RCA audio settings

Tags: audio, rca

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian Lite Release 10.  I will be running squeezelite on it for it to function as a squeezebox player.  I need to have sound output to RCA jacks to plug into my stereo amplifier.  I do not need RCA video. I am running the raspberry pi headless so I do not need video at all.

1. Do I need to enable Composite in raspi-config A8 Raspberry Pi 4 video output options to get RCA audio from 3.5mm jack or is there a sound-only RCA output setting somewhere?
2. Will I need to change any other settings to have RCA sound output?
3. Can I use a TRS 3.5mm audio cable with just two (audio) RCA jacks at other end or do I need to use a TRRS 3.5mm audio jack with three RCA jacks.  I am worried that using a TRS will short the ground and video contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 No you don't need to enable composite on a Pi4 to get analogue/headphone audio.

2 Using 'sudo raspi-config', select 'System Options','Audio','Headphones'

[image]

3 You can use a regular 3.5mm TRS audio cable. The Pi TRRS socket is designed to allow video to be shorted.

Comment: Thanks @CoderMike.  Is "headphone" output the same as output suitable for line inputs (RCA) to an amplifier?  I thought that headphone output might be amplified and thus not suitable for line input and I thought that headphone output and line output are designed for different impedences.

Comment: The headphone output works fine for line inputs - that's what I use to an amplifier.